# Test a webservice which is available remotely

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I can access a web service from remote machine through vpn.

And cannot access that web service from my local machine. I tried to install Visual studio in remote machine but there is no enough space.

I would like to create a web application and deploy it in remote machine, which will test that web service. Is it possible? or please let me know how to test that web service through my mvc web application.

Comment: Just buy a new hard disk.

Comment: which errors you recieve?